# strtotime('-1 month') returning wrong date if month have 31 days

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying make a function to return the exact date of previous months.

That is a example of my code:

```
// Dates in TimeStamp
$ts_now =  strtotime('now');
$ts_month1 = strtotime("-1 month", $ts_now);
$ts_month2 = strtotime("-2 month", $ts_now);
$ts_month3 = strtotime("-3 month", $ts_now);

// Dates Formated
$date_now = date('Y-m-d', $ts_now);
$date_month1 = date('Y-m-d', $ts_month1);
$date_month2 = date('Y-m-d', $ts_month2);
$date_month3 = date('Y-m-d', $ts_month3);

//Output
echo $date_now;    //2020-04-30
echo $date_month1; //2020-03-30
echo $date_month2; //2020-03-01
echo $date_month3; //2020-01-30
```

The problem is in `$date_month2` that represents February, the **output is 2020-03-01 instead 2020-02-29** and I suppose that problem will happen in months who have 30 days when present date have 31 days.

What is the best way to resolve that?

Comment: That all depends on what your expected result is. Last day of the previous month? 30 days previous? 28 days?

Comment: The result is dynamic, I need the exact date of -x month ago. If today was day 31, I would need 03/30/20 or 02/29/2020.

Comment: So you need *the last day of the previous month*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see working with the end of the month can be problematic because of how PHP works with dates. Your best bet is to go back to the beginning of the month, do your date math (i.e. go backwards in time), and then go to the date you want. That way you can check to see if the current day is greater than the number of days in month. If so, use the last day of the month instead.

```
function getMonthsAgo(int $n): string {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $day  = $date->format('j');
    $date->modify('first day of this month')->modify('-' . $n . ' months');
    if ($day > $date->format('t')) {
        $day = $date->format('t');
    }
    $date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'), $day);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

// Dates Formated
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');
$date_month1 = getMonthsAgo(1);
$date_month2 = getMonthsAgo(2);
$date_month3 = getMonthsAgo(3);

//Output
echo $date_now;
echo $date_month1;
echo $date_month2;
echo $date_month3;
```

Output:

```
2020-04-30
2020-03-30
2020-02-29
2020-01-30
```

Comment: I think I can put some validations and use this code in my project.
I've been working for so long that I couldn't think of such a simple solution. Thanks man, and sorry for the dumb ask.

Comment: It's not a dumb ask. This is a common problem that most developers trip over at some point in their career

Comment: How I use the same code to get -2, -3 or more months ago?

Comment: `P1M` is short for "period 1 month". So to go back two months use `P2M`. Three months would be `P3M`, etc.

Comment: So I only need change the P1M?

Comment: Yes. Let me write a function for you that makes this easy.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I would appreciate it. My version is 7.3. In my function, I only need get the exact day of each 11 months ago, but I having these problems.